# Pass PropertyChangedEventHandler in constructor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I'm trying to pass a PropertyChangedEventHandler as a parameter in a constructor, the goal being that the parameter, when passed, can be subscribed to the PropertyChanged event in a base class.

```cs
public class Caller : BaseClass{

    public Caller() : base(OnPropertyChanged){
        //
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs eventArgs){
        // handle stuff
    }
}

public class BaseClass : INotifyPropertyChanged{

    public BaseClass(PropertyChangedEventHandler handler){
        PropertyChanged += handler;
    }
}
```

Now, I know what you're thinking: why don't you just inject Caller instead of the method? Well, firstly, you can't inject `this` in a ctor. Also, these classes are part of a parent/child hierarchy in which parents know their children but not the other way around (and it should be like that in my case), so I can't just go ahead and tell the child about its parent and hook up to the `PropertyChanged`that way.

The compiler is telling me that:

> Cannot access non-static method 'OnPropertyChanged' in static context.

I can't make my `OnPropertyChanged` static. That makes no sense.

Is there a way to solve this while staying within my restrictions? A workaround is fine, as long as `Caller` is never directly passed into `BaseClass`.

EDIT:
To clarify, the `Caller` can not reference `PropertyChanged` itself, because it would be the wrong one (it would be its own, and not the child's). I've just hidden that away to keep the code clean. For those interested, there's actually a `Func` there where I call the base class that does the creating of the child and takes in the `OnPropertyChanged` method.

Comment: I would move the OnPropertyChanged to the Base class, change it to protected virtual, and then remove the constructor parameters.  Change the base constructor to `PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;`.  When the child needs to raise the property, you would use `OnPropertyChanged(this, etc);`

Answer (score 1):

> why don't you just inject Caller instead of the method? Well, firstly, you can't inject this in a ctor

If you understand that, then you should also understand why you can't use the method name. When you use a method name in a place where a `delegate` reference is needed, the compiler automatically generates code for you to create a `delegate` instance.

When the method is an instance method, the `delegate` requires an instance reference in addition to the target method itself. When you don't provide an instance explicitly, what reference is used? That's right: `this`.

But as you've already noted, you can't "inject" `this` in the constructor. Or more properly, you're not allowed to use `this` outside of the constructor until the object has been fully initialized. Not being able to use the method name there is exactly the same as not being able to use `this` in the same context.

The correct way to do something like this, where a derived class needs to be able to provide the implementation for a method that the base class wants to be able to call is to declare the method in the base class as `virtual` or `abstract` and then have the derived class override the method.

For example:

```
public class Caller : BaseClass{

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs eventArgs){
        // handle stuff
    }
}

public abstract class BaseClass : INotifyPropertyChanged{

    protected abstract void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs eventArgs);
}
```

Note I've also removed the `sender` parameter from the method declaration. Typically, this pattern is used both to provide a base implementation mechanism for *raising* the event, as well as a way for derived classes to have some control over the event (such as doing some processing before or after raising the event, or even modifying the event args before the event is raised). As such, `sender` is always `this` and so there's no need for it to be included.

In other words, more typically the base class would in fact have an implementation, rather than making the method `abstract`, and that implementation would be where the event is raised.

Comment: Thanks Peter, but that's not what I'm looking for. I may have not been specific enough (did you see my edit?). `BaseClass` is already abstract. Moreover `BaseClass`'s OnPropertyChanged would be the wrong one to hook up because it would be the caller's own, and not that of the child in the parent/child hierarchy. That's why I need some way to inject the method. 1-up though, for clarifying details on `this` and the method being an instance method and essentially being equivalent to passing `this`.

Comment: _"BaseClass's OnPropertyChanged would be the wrong one to hook up because it would be the caller's own"_ -- you misunderstand. I'm not talking about "hooking up" an event handler at all. The normal idiom here is for the method itself to be the one to raise the event; i.e. it's called when the event is supposed to be raised, rather than it being called _by_ raising the event.

Comment: "Hooking up" may well be the wrong term to use, but I'm not misunderstanding your example. My point is that in your example, when the event is raised, the wrong object would be notified. I may need to make a better example, because it doesn't seem like the fact that `BaseClass` and `Caller` are not the same instance in my example is clear enough. One last go: `Parent` and `Child` are instances of `Caller`. `Parent` provides a `Func` when calling `base()` which handles constructing `Child`. `Child` needs some way to notify `Parent` of PropertyChanged on its properties without a ref to `Parent`.

Comment: _"it doesn't seem like the fact that `BaseClass` and `Caller` are not the same instance in my example is clear enough"_ -- `Caller` inherits `BaseClass`, and its constructor necessarily calls the base class constructor _on the same instance_. So, yes...if you think you are dealing with two different instances of `BaseClass` here, you are either seriously confused or the code example in your question has nothing to do with the scenario you have in mind. Please fix your question so it correctly represents what you actually want to ask.